# How to get result from Spark after submitting a job via REST API?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-standalone

When I submit a Spark job through API `/v1/submissions/create` on port 6066 and check the status of it by `/v1/submissions/status/{driver-id}`, I only get something like this

```json
{
  "action" : "SubmissionStatusResponse",
  "driverState" : "FINISHED",
  "serverSparkVersion" : "3.1.2",
  "submissionId" : "driver-20211226153006-0000",
  "success" : true,
  "workerHostPort" : "xx.xx.xx.xx:xx",
  "workerId" : "worker-20211226152727-xx.xx.xx.xx-xx"
}
```

Is there any way to get more information about this job, such as execution time, memory used or the output of this job, etc?